# Splitting a Polygon by a MultiPolygon is unsupported. Both geom columns are MultiPolygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-analyst, geometry, multi-geometry

I'm trying To st_split() on two tables. the output is like this: 
`Splitting a Polygon by a MultiPolygon is unsupported`
 . Although both fields are Multipolygons. Created new columns where the geometry type is not specified. try:

```
create table processing.split_20 as (
  select 
  inventory_elements.ogc_fid as inv_id, seg_20.ogc_fid as seg_id,
  ST_Split(inventory_elements.geom, seg_20.geom)
  from input_d.inventory_elements, input_d.seg_20
  )
```

-nothing changes - Splitting a Polygon by a MultiPolygon is unsupported and the types have not changed again both multipolygons

although after creating the columns and set the data I initiated alter to geometrii

```
ALTER TABLE input_d.inventory_elements ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(Geometry, 4326)
```

Comment: Check the [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html): splitting Polygons by *any type* of Polygon is not supported, it has to be a LineString! Use e.g. `ST_ExteriorRing` as blade.